# How to compare two user date in a table

Tags: laravel

I want to compare two user date in table, The first user is "user" and the second user is "myrefuser".
Both of them is having record in stagebonus database and have a column name updated_at. 
I want to compare if "myrefuser" date is >= "user".
Please me out

```
$user = Auth::user();
$myrefuser = User::where("user_id",$user->sponsor_id)->first();
$myrefauto = StageBonus::where("user_id",$myref->user_id)->where("status",1)->first();
$userauto = StageBonus::where("user_id",$user->user_id)->where("status",1)->first();
```

This is what have done and it return null

```
$h = StageBonus::
        where('user_id', $myrefuser->user_id)
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->whereDate('updated_at', '<=', '$user->updated_at')->first();
```

Comment: Laravel comes with `Carbon`, so it should be pretty easy to parse `updated_at` into a `Carbon` date (if it isn't already), then use straight comparison `$date >= $otherDate`

Comment: can you please create a demo with it

Comment: You're not even going to try anything first?

Comment: The query looks fine. I would bet that you aren't actually matching a row. You may want to post the rows that you are working with.

Comment: You’re trying to access an object inside single quotes. Either use the speech mark/quotes & curly brace approach or remove the single quotes.

Comment: Good eye @Josh Murray

Comment: Thanks i really appreciate you all. @OneLiner that's actually where  my problem is have not get it